# Inheritance error in Ruby 2.x when overriding methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using this method as a way to provide some custom database configuration in `application.rb`, It was working perfectly on rails `4.1.4` and ruby `1.9.3` and recently I updated to ruby `2.3.0` and it started throwing this error:

```
NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `database_configuration'
  method_missing at ../gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95
```

code below.

```
module MyApp 
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ... config 
    config.encoding = "utf-8" 

    def config.database_configuration
      parsed = super
      raise parsed.to_yaml  # Replace this line to add custom connections to the hash from database.yml
    end
  end
end
```

Any one has any ideas what's changed in new ruby for this behaviour. I did a pry breakpoint inside the `config.database_configuration` method and called super in the console and that seems to work and give output without error.

Comment: Hey is this `raise` thing intentional or you misspelled it? is it `return`?

Comment: In `rails 4.2.0`, `ruby 2.3.1` I could not recreate this error. But the exception you intend to raise.